# Is it legal to build your own car navigational system?

Tags: united-states, traffic, north-carolina

I am trying to build my own car navigational system and vehicle informational system. I am in North Carolina so NC G.S. § 20-136.1 is the main reference point I am starting from. This just explains that computers are forbidden and their exceptions. I am using a raspberry pi and making a touchscreen that is mounted in my cup holder. Whenever driving it is only to be used as a navigational system and a vehicle informational system. Are there any previous cases or references to what classifies as a computer and as a navigational system or cases where people got tried for things like this. Is it also possible to get written approval from a department in NC on the system I am making.

Other states will be driving through and would like to know the legal status of my system. VA, MD, District of Columbia

Comment: All navigation systems are computers but programed to have the sole, special purpose of navigation. Why do you think what you are making will not be an "aftermarket navigation system" - which are explicitly allowed? Do you have am mode that exposes the computer terminal on the touch screen?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite laws are tricky. Therefore I am making sure what I make is completely in a green zone. Making sure what I have, is classified as a navigational system and not a computer is critical so I am exempt from that law. The system I am trying to integrate is [headunit-display](https://github.com/viktorgino/headunit-desktop/wiki/Screenshots)  which contains android auto and a few other functions. In driving mode there is no terminal. Is a terminal a requirement for a device to be classified as a computer or are there other requirements? Is there a particular case or law that decides that?